# What is the meaning of the "@" prefix on some D attributes?

Tags: syntax, d

The D Programming Language has at least two attributes prefixed with the "@" symbol:

- `@disable`
- `@property`

What sort of meaning is "@" supposed to convey? I can't seem to locate anything relevant in the documentation.

Also, why is `__gshared` the only attribute with two leading underscores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has no meaning.

Yes, that probably wasn't what you were hoping to hear -- but that's what they've said in the newsgroups.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the relevant info in the newsgroups, for reference? I gave a kinda speculative answer (that might be totally wrong), but will remove it in light of new info, once confirmed.

Comment: @mgibsonbr: It's kinda hard to search for, but I'll look for it... it's already been asked a bunch of times on the newsgroup, and this is the answer given. (It certainly wasn't *intended* to be this way, but that's what it is right now.)

Comment: @mgibsonbr: The only thread I could find is [this](http://www.digitalmars.com/pnews/read.php?server=news.digitalmars.com&group=digitalmars.D&artnum=105272) which says "Currently, there doesn't seem to be any clear definition of which attributes should be prefixed with @ and which shouldn't", but I've seen it a million times, in a lot more clear language... it's just hard to search for "@" in there...

Comment: @mgibsonbr: Ah, [here](http://www.digitalmars.com/webnews/newsgroups.php?art_group=digitalmars.D&article_id=117883)'s a better one: *"if you dig a little in the DMD source, you'll see there is no difference in how these attributes and other keywords are processed once you have passed the parsing stage, they just become flags on data structures, just like regular keywords often do. [...] To me, the explanation to differentiate the two is quite simple: an historical incident made all new keywords added after a certain date use the `@attribute` syntax."*

Comment: Thanks for the info, now I see it's not related to Java's annotations in any way. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Definitely not what I was hoping to hear, but thanks for the supporting links! Syntax inconsistencies like these drive me crazy.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, at the time there was lots of discussion to add annotations. At the time D had several keywords it needed to add, and also properties were being discussed. Suddenly @ property was added, and @ safe... followed. This made me an others think that attributes were approved, but maybe no such intention was there. http://www.prowiki.org/wiki4d/wiki.cgi?LanguageDevel/DIPs/DIP6

Answer (score 2):

The `@` doesn't really mean anything at this point. All of the `@x` words are function attributes. The `@` was tacked on pretty much just to save keywords. So, in general, newer attributes have `@` on them and older ones don't (though there was some shuffling around of that a while back where there was some debate over whether some of the attributes should have `@` or not). If they were redone from scratch without caring what other languages have done, then you might have gotten `@` on all of the function attributes, but there was no way that stuff like `@public` was going to happen, since it would have just made porting code harder for no real benefit. The end result is that what got `@` and what didn't is fairly arbitrary. You just have to remember which attributes start with `@` and which don't, but that's not all that much different from having to learn new keywords. It's just that these are prefixed with `@` so that they aren't actually keywords and don't reduce the number of legal identifiers in the language.

Now, there's definitely a desire among many in the D community to use `@` for custom attributes in the future, in which case, `@` would indicate a custom attribute in the cases where the name used wasn't one built into the language, but for all of the ones built into the language, it pretty much just amounts to saving a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

As Mehrdad shows (see the links in the comments), there's no special meaning to "@", they are how they are just for historical reasons.

As for your other question, `__gshared` isn't the only keyword with two underscores, there's also `__thread` and `__traits`. This naming convention is commonly used to denote internal data structures, which need to be exposed for practical reasons but are not "safe" to use in all cases (i.e. more a hack than a well-established feature). I'm not sure whether or not the D language follows this convention, but seeing [this quote](http://dlang.org/attribute.html#gshared) from the docs I believe that's the case:

> __gshared is disallowed in safe mode.

I'm searching for more info about `__thread` and `__traits` (which indeed are not attributes), but so far could find very little.

Comment: Are you sure __thread is valid in D? __thread is a C/C++ storage class (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v101v121/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp101.aix.doc/language_ref/thread.html) marking data thread-local. But thread-local storage is used by default in D so __thread isn't really necessary.

Comment: @jpf all I know is that it's a [reserved identifier](http://dlang.org/lex.html). Maybe it was reserved but never used, that's why I haven't found any specific documentation about it...